How to set up UART1 on PR Pico with Zephyr (Devicetree)?
So I try to use the UART1 interface on my RP Pico via Zephyr, but it wont work. My problem is, I do not know how to set up UART1 in the devicetree. UART0 is usabel by default and everything works fine with that.
My plan is to communicate over UART0 with my computer, to show some messges and use it for debugging. This works fine so far, without problems. I want to use UART1 to communicate with a GPS sensor (the communication part works fine, I tried it with UART0). The only thing that doesn´t work is the set up for UART1...
In zephyrproject\zephyr\boards\arm\rpi_pico\rpi_pico-common.dtsi the UART0 is defined:
&uart0 {
    current-speed = <115200>;
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart0_default>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
};

and in rpi_pico-pinctrl.dtsi
    uart0_default: uart0_default {
        group1 {
            pinmux = <UART0_TX_P0>;
        };
        group2 {
            pinmux = <UART0_RX_P1>;
            input-enable;
        };
    };

But why isn´t UART1 not predefined or better, how do I set up UART1 to use it in the same way as UART0?

"In rpi_pico-common.dtsi the UART0 is defined:
&uart0 { ... }" - No, that is not the complete node for the UART0 device. It's only some additional (board-specific) properties to the original (generic) node which has the label uart0. IOW you are just showing us a snippet of the Device Tree. Have you even looked at the complete Device Tree for your board?

"But why isn´t UART1 not predefined ..." - That question is based on a faulty premise because a node for UART1 is defined in rp2040.dtsi. But since that include file is only intended for a base/minimal configuration, most of the devices of the SoC are disabled. Those base properties can be modified/replaced or new/more properties added to the base node using another included file or in the .dts file itself. The issue is that the board DT you're trying to use is a minimal board configuration. Devices typically are not enabled in a configuration unless there is a need.

you can simply add it yourself in the devicetree.
Thanks to @sawdust in know now it is the enableing explicitly what is missing. The rp2040 has uart1 defined, but in your current device tree it is not connected with real PINs, so not enabled.
(status = "okay" or disabled is the enableing i know ...)
By looking into the datasheet of the Raspiberry Pico which is RP2040:
https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf
In Section: 1.4.3. GPIO Functions
There is UART1 mentioned with GPIO Pins.
Also there is mentioned which Pins you are interferring when using the 2nd UART.
You can create an overlay file or use the "rpi_pico-pinctrl.dtsi" directly.
tl;dr:
With snippet:
uart1_default: uart1_default {
    group1 {
        pinmux = <UART1_TX_P4>;
    };
    group2 {
        pinmux = <UART1_RX_P5>;
        input-enable;
    };
};

Valid Pins can be found in the file: rpi-pico-rp2040-pinctrl.h
at: zephyr/include/zephyr/dt-bindings/pinctrl/rpi-pico-rp2040-pinctrl.h
Of course one need also this piece of code:
&uart1 {
current-speed = <115200>;
status = "okay";
pinctrl-0 = <&uart1_default>;
pinctrl-names = "default";
};


"I dont know why it is not defined yet" - You and the OP are conflating "defining" and "enabling". If a DT node labeled uart1 was not already defined in (the included) rp2040.dtsi file, then your reference of &uart1 to that label would be invalid. IOW nodes for uart0 & uart1 do exist in the dtsi file for a generic implementation, but only the former device is (later)  enabled for that minimnal board configuration. Instead of modifying existing DT source files for a new configuration or board, you should create a new top-level .dts file with your modifications.

Thanks! I didn't know that. :)
Actually I always use custom boards and there is a defined way how todo things.
In the different specifications and board revision I just create those *.overlay files.
Also a *.conf file I created always, this is the way I override things for specific boards.
I never touch the orignal dts or dtsi files.
